# Mapear un json como tabla html

Tags: html, json

Tengo el siguiente json:

```
    {
    "codEmp": 5555,
    "empleado": [{
        "codEmp": "0001",
        "descEmp": "Juan Perez",
        "importe": {
            "minimo": 10,
            "maximo": 2500
        },
        "pariente": [{
            "parentesco": "esposa",
            "nombre": "Julia"
        }, {
            "parentesco": "hijo",
            "nombre": "Marcelo"
        }],
        "tarjetas": [{
            "codTarjeta": "V",
            "descTarjeta": "Visa"
        }]
    }, {
        "codEmp": "1488",
        "descEmp": "Sergio",
        "importe": {
            "minimo": 100,
            "maximo": 25000
        },
        "pariente": [{
            "parentesco": "esposa",
            "nombre": "Fernanda"
        }, {
            "parentesco": "hijo",
            "nombre": "Maria"
        }],
        "tarjetas": [{
            "codTarjeta": "V",
            "descTarjeta": "Visa"
        }, {
            "codTarjeta": "A",
            "descTarjeta": "America"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Necesitaría visualizarlo en una pagina html.

Estoy probando con http://gijgo.com/Grid/Demos/LocalDataSample, si tengo "codEmp" y una lista lo puedo hacer, pero se me complico cuando tengo una lista dentro de otra lista para mostrarlo en una tabla.

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), 
puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
para mas información consulte el siguiente [enlace](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). 

Consulta la librería [json2html](http://json2html.com/).

Answer (score 1):

No queda muy claro si quieres mostrar el json en si, o meter su contenido en una tabla.

Pero ¿porque no pruebas con `json_decode` de `php` y vas accediendo a los campos?

```
$json_decodificado = json_decode($tu_json)

echo $json_decodificado->codEmp (5555)
echo $json_decodificado-> empleado->codEmp (0001)
```

Esto es con `php`, como no especificas con que lenguaje trabajas, espero que te solucione el problema o te conduzca a la solución.

Te dejo la documentación de `php`:

> http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Un saludo

Comment: Necesito agregar el contenido a una tabla. Para el frontend estoy utilizando bootstrap y jquery en archivos html. Gracias por la respuesta pero no estoy utilizando PHP.

Comment: Entonces echale un vistazo a como parsearlo con jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/ Aquí ya no te puedo ayudar tanto que no lo he usado nunca. Pero la manera de proceder es la misma, deserializas el json y accedes a los campos para mostrar su valor.